# Android delivery information in Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns

Tags: android, sms

How to check if the message is delivered in the sms content provider (Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns fields)

Answer (score 1):

By STATUS field

```
mCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms"),
                arrayOf("body", "date", "type", "status"),
                "address like ?",
                arrayOf("%$id"),
                "date asc")

val status = mCursor.getInt(3)
if (status == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Deliverd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
} else if (status == 32)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sent and waiting for delivery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
} else if (status == 64) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
}
```

[Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns - STATUS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns)